# Bootstrap checkbuttons with icons does not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the need to add checkbuttons to my table and I want use the Bootstrap Button for this.

I found a snippet on the web that combine icons with buttons and the JS code to define buttons behavior. Cause this code is with Glyphicons, in another discussion I asked for an alternative and I obtained it; now I'm using fontawesome.

So, I've done this steps:

1. Copy the folder with the min.css file in my app folder, under: `src/main/webapp/static/font-awesome-css/font-awesome.min.css`
2. Include the folder path in my home page with this syntax: `<link href="../../static/font-awesome-css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">`
3. Use this snippet: [BootStrap Checkbutton With Icons](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/7nQMK); in particular, I used only one button in my Data Table, this one:

`{
                        "data":   null,
                        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                            return '<span class="button-checkbox"><button type="button" class="btn" data-color="primary">Select</button><input type="checkbox" style="display: none" checked /></span>';
                        }
                    },` 
while for the JS function i tried both an external file to include and to put directly inside the data table file.

Well, the problem is that when i load my app, the button does not have the icons, does not change after click and it's not selected: at start, this is the situation (the not working button is "Select"):

[image: check not working]

Can you see the grey buttn without icons? Well, after clicking the situation does not change.

What I am doing wrong?

UPDATE 01 Sept: seems that the problem is where the js code is putted.
As first try, I've putted it in the section where I define the table printing; the results are showed after a form interaction, so I've associted the code with the submit button behavior. The problem persist, but I've noticed a change: when the table appair, for 2 second the button are showed correctly and then they became grey.

Comment: Hi Luca, it seems to me that nothing is wrong (but the code isn't complete, so...I'm just guessing).
Have a look here, where everything is fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/LaurMe/u7aajfLd

Answer (score 1):

My best guess whould be that the JS isn't implemented correctly since this is the part that does everything you want:

[image: JS]

**EDIT:**

This might be more helpfull to post too, if you look at there source code they implemented the JS directly into there HTML with a script so I guess you also need to do this.

Source code: view-source:https://s.bootsnipp.com/iframe/7nQMK

[image]